# localStorage Save and retrieve CSS of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to create an application where a user can dynamically change a div's background image. 
What's bugging me is the fact that I cannot save the div's background in localStorage.

Here's the code I've come up with but it's not working:

To save::

```
$(".abc").on('click', function(){
localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('backgroundImage'));
});
```

To retrieve::

```
if (localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg') === null) {
localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('backgroundImage'));
} else {
$(".bodybg").html(localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg'));
}
```

Comment: Try $(".bodybg").css('background-image') instead $(".bodybg").css('backgroundImage')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backgroundImage` is **not valid CSS property**, try `background-image` instead

```
$(".abc").on('click', function(){
    localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('background-image'));
    });
```

**To retrieve**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg') === null) {
localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('background-image'));
} else {
$(".bodybg").html(localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg'));
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

use background-image instead of backgroundImage, and on retrieve something rather like:

```
$(".bodybg").css("background-image", localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong css property and your then changing the html of the target element incorrectly...

This should work:

```
$(".abc").on('click', function(){
   localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('background-image'));
});
```

Then:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg') === null) {
   localStorage.setItem('contentbodybg', $(".bodybg").css('background-image'));
} else {
   $(".bodybg").css('background-image', localStorage.getItem('contentbodybg'));
}
```